# How to correctly set a UISwitch ON state using a NSManagedObject boolean attribute type?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, casting

Lets say I have the following setup:

```
....
UISwitch gpsSwitch;

// the below object has a gpsEnabled property of type boolean - default NO
NSManagedObject *typeObject;
....
```

How exactly do I go about properly calling:

```
self.gpsSwitch.on = [self.typeObject valueForKey:@"gpsEnabled"];
```

This always returns *warning: passing argument 1 of 'setOn:' makes integer from pointer without a cast.* and does not work.

I've tried:

```
(BOOL)[self.typeObject valueForKey:@"gpsEnabled"];
(NSInteger)[self.typeObject valueForKey:@"gpsEnabled"];
```

and none of these casts seem to work? What's fix? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self.typeObject valueForKey:@"gpsEnabled"]` returns and NSNumber object.

`[[self.typeObject valueForKey:@"gpsEnabled"] boolValue]` returns a BOOL.

`self.gpsSwitch.on` needs a BOOL.

Even though you setup boolean or int or whatever in your core data model, they are always retreived/set as NSNumbers.  Somewhat confusing.  I like to make accessors in my NSManagedObject subclasses that do the conversion for me.

Comment: Thank you sir! That's exactly it.